# Running skype at the same time as certain other applications disconnects internet

Tags: windows-7, virtualbox, skype

If I'm running skype and try to run certain other applications at the same time, I lose my wifi connection, and it only reconnects when I close the other program. It happens especially with virtualbox (when I launch a VM) and steam (when I start a game). This happens consistently. Literally as soon as I start a VM instance, for example, the connection drops. As soon as I close the VM, it reconnects instantly.

I've turned off UPnP in skype, and told it not to use ports 80 and 443. Unfortunately, using a wired connection is not an option currently.

How can I diagnose what's going on?

Comment: When you say you lose your WiFi connection, do you mean that you can no longer reach your router? (If you mean you lose your Internet connectivity, how do you know that's because you lost your WiFi connection?)

Comment: Good point. It's just the connection to the router - my other devices still have internet connectivity.